# Excel VBA Right Header set Font Size to 20 - Excel decides size 409 is better

Tags: excel, vba, header, font-size

I'm trying to make a simple macro to change the date displayed on the right header to be 'tomorrow's' date. When I try to set the default format of my headers and footers to 20 and then run the macro, Excel changes the font size to 11. But when i specify in the VBA code to change to 20, Excel increases the font size to 409!
The current script that I'm using is as follows:

```
Sub tomorrow()

Dim today As Date

Dim tomorrow As Date

today = Date

tomorrow = Date + 1

With ActiveSheet.PageSetup

    .DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = False
    .RightHeader = "&""Calibri""&20" & Format(tomorrow, "dd/mm/yyyy")
    
End With
End Sub
```

Can anyone spot where I'm going wrong? I just need the font size to be 20, it seems so simple, but I'm stumped... Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add a space after the 20 so that it doesn't have the day number appended to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`"&""Calibri""&20" & Format(tomorrow, "dd/mm/yyyy")` evolves to `&"Calibri"&2020.04.2020` (of course depending on the current date). As as result, the Font size will be read as `2020`, and as the maximum font size in Excel is 409, you will get that as font size of your header.

To prevent that the day is concatenated directly with the font size, you should simply add a space - this will do no harm as the right header is right aligned anyhow (this is exactly what Excel does if you set the header manually).

```
RightHeader = "&""Calibri""&20 " & Format(tomorrow, "dd/mm/yyyy")
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot! I knew there was some tricky little detail I was overlooking.